# What is the meaning of this warning in windows administrative events - DNS Client Events

Tags: windows-7, event-log, event-viewer

Sometimes I open profile of a user and he has write the address of his site there, but I don't remember when was the last time I clicked that address. But I have some warnings in **computer management\event viewer\administrative events** in some days.

I want know why should I have such this warning while I never opened that site and what is the meaning of this?

( I am using windows 7, and if it is needed I can give the address of the site).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that windows tried to contact the DNS servers of your FAI (or the one you manually specified in the connection properties) and that the connection timeout.

Maybe you had a loss of connection, or the DNS server were out a few times, or they where wrongly configure.

Comment: There were some wrongs in the connection, but why does that site address that is in a web page is in the warning? and I never opened that site!